# Griffiths Elementary Particles Eq. 8.48 Chromodynamics 2nd edition

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, coulombs-law, quarks, approximations, strong-force

Griffiths describes the quark-antiquark amplitude (First order approximation considering its Feynman Diagram page 289) as similar to the electron-muon amplitude. He compares them in a way such that you could exchange $\alpha \to \alpha_sf$ and you'll have the respective amplitude (where $f$ is a color factor). Moreover, he says

> Therefore, the potential describing the $q\bar{q}$ interaction is the same as that acting in electrodynamics between two opposite charges (to wit: the Coulomb potential),
> only with a replaced by $f\alpha_s$,...

$V_{q\bar{q}}=-f\frac{\alpha_s \hbar c}{r}$

There is a similar discussion of this in chapter 5 page 171 about Quarkonium where he says:

> ...quarks are bound to the strong force; we don't know what potential to use, in place of Coulomb's law(...) In principle, these are derivable from quantum chromodynamics, but no one yet knows how to do the calculation.

He then goes on constructing a potential considering restrictions about *what the potential should obey*. I'm not sure what is the justification for a strong force potential accepting that quark-antiquark amplitude is similar to the electron-muon amplitude. He didn't discuss potentials since chapter 5, so it's difficult to understand how we could suddenly link both pictures.